# Vectorize Evaluations of Meshgrid Points in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization, repeat, replicate

I need the "for" loop in the following representative section of code to run as efficiently as possible. The mean function in the code is acting as a representative placeholder for my own function.

```
x = linspace(-1,1,15);
y = linspace(2,4,15);
[xgrid, ygrid] = meshgrid(x,y);
mc = rand(100000,1);
z=zeros(size(xgrid));

for i=1:length(xgrid)
    for j=1:length(ygrid)
        z(i,j) = mean(xgrid(i,j) + ygrid(i,j) + xgrid(i,j)*ygrid(i,j)*mc);
    end
end
```

I have vectorized the code and improved its speed by about 2.5 times by building a matrix in which mc is replicated for each grid point. My implementation results in a very large matrix (3 x 22500000) filled with repeated data. I've mitigated the memory penalty of this approach by converting the matrix to single precision, but it seems like there should be a more efficient way to do what I want that avoids replicating so much data.

Comment: have you considered only duplicate `mc` for one dimension and use loop for the outer loop? also consider moving `i` to the inner loop.

Comment: For such large arrays, vectorisation will likely cause memory problems. For loops are not always inefficient, Matlab's JIT compilation helps for smaller problems, and better memory usage for larger problems. You could consider using a parallel for loop for the outer loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) with few [`reshapes`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) -

```
A = bsxfun(@times,y,x.'); %//'
B = bsxfun(@plus,y,x.');  %//'
C = mean(bsxfun(@plus,bsxfun(@times,mc,reshape(A,1,[])) , reshape(B,1,[])),1);
z_out = reshape(C,numel(x),[]).';
```